# Why the "next" field in ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry is final

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap, java.util.concurrent

I'm reading reading the source code of java.util.ConcurrentHashMap and find that the `next` field in ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry is final. There are two operations that is possible to modify the value of `next`:add and remove. But those two operations cat be done thread safely even though the `next` field is not final. So I cann't understand why the `next` field is final, can anyone tell me why? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`final` on `next` is needed to ensure that reading threads see the initialized value of the field, because (most of) reads of `ConcurrentHashMap` happen without synchronization.

Note that, for example, `value` is not `final`, therefore reading thread can see a non-initialized value (`null`) in that field, and have to recheck it under synchronization in that case:

```
    V get(Object key, int hash) {
        if (count != 0) { // read-volatile
            HashEntry<K,V> e = getFirst(hash);
            while (e != null) {
                if (e.hash == hash && key.equals(e.key)) {
                    V v = e.value;
                    if (v != null)
                        return v;
                    return readValueUnderLock(e); // recheck
                }
                e = e.next;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: so, final makes sure that initialized value of field is seen correctly by reading threads. But why is HashEntry class itself final in ConcurrentHashMap?